# Add New Classes to Yolov7 Object Detection Model

Tags: object, detection, transfer-learning, yolov7

I have been trying to apply transfer learning technique on Yolov7 (https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) object detection model which in simpler word adding new classes into the model.

I have been following the tutorial and instruction from (https://community.ultralytics.com/t/how-to-combine-weights-to-detect-from-multiple-datasets/38) that discusses how to configure the dataset yaml file. However, the model eventually became unable to detect anything anymore. What could be the issue?

PS: I tried to freeze the backbone of Yolov7 so it won't be trained.

[dataset yaml file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki4e2.png)
[code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrZXG.png)